# Java program doesn't start on Unix machine

Tags: unix, jvm, java

When I start Java application from command line on AIX 6.1 machine the application just doesn't start. All I get is a blinking cursor, hitting CTRL+C doesn't help. It seats in the list of processes all the time. 
Even running the following command produces the same result so I don't think it is program related.

```
java -version
```

Cursor is blinking on the next line and nothing happens. When I open second session and type

```
ps -ef
```

I get the following:

```
 tomcat 32243914 31850686   0 13:50:27  pts/7  0:00 -ksh
 tomcat  5439538 32243914   1 13:50:50  pts/7  0:00 /usr/java6/jre/bin/java -version
```

On Windows my program runs just fine. So I think it is JRE or Unix related.

I'm not a Unix expert so I would appreciate any suggestions on how to trouble shoot this.

Comment: Which flavour of *nix? How did you install Java? Any other output you can provide?

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: Would you enter the command-line you are running ? And was this try applied to a kind of very simple HelloWorld that just uses System.out.println()?

Comment: Without code we are just a bunch of people poking you with a stick ...

Comment: Do you mean first there's no java process but after running `java -version` there is one, even after execution of that command ended? If so, we need more information.

Comment: try to navigate to the java binary in the file system and just run the java binary from there then report back it should output something like this.           .............                       Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

Comment: To see if it hangs at some syscall, you could use strace.

Comment: The app isn't a daemon is it?  Should it have a UI?  Are you running it over a ssh session? If so have you configured X to send the display to your machine?  What does the app do?  What does it do on windows?

Comment: if your current java program is complex, using many libraries/features, try running a simple "hello world" java program. if it runs, you will know that something is with program, not system. this may not be of much help, but without code all we can do is predict things.

Comment: Well, I gave an example with running java -version. There is no point in having code here.

Answer (score 1):

sounds strange , it seems that your process does not give hands back... No return 
Do you have top binary installed on your AIX machine ?
Could you check that this machine follows the long list of requirements to run the java binary ? You may find useful information on the IBM java package webpage I guess...

Do you have lsof binaries or any other standard debuging tool ? lsof  would point to any problem related to your AIX machine

HTH
Jerome

Comment: Can you please edit this so that it is more of an *answer* and less interrogative? We require answers to be answers; interaction with the OP for more information are usually restricted to comments (which you will need more rep to leave).

Answer (score 0):

We have an intermittent similar issue with Java on Solaris.  Sometimes rebooting the machine helps.  Other times we have to remove the .java file from the user's home directory.  Very random and annoying.  The box can be up for months before it happens, or mere hours...